# showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection on ConnectivityManager

Tags: java, android

i got an error when i just open my app.. on the first screen it show splash activity ... and there's an error

> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

and this one the code on my splash activity, dunno on what section it got warn..

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.xxx.xx.helper.SessionManager;
import com.xxx.xx.util.ConnectionDetector;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    protected SessionManager session;

    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    checking();
                }

            }

        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public void checking() {

        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        if(isInternetPresent) {
            session.checkLogin();
            finish();
        } else {
            alert.showAlertDialog(Splash.this, "No Connection", "Check Your Internet Connection.",false);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

and this one my connection manager code ..

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {
    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (info != null) {
                    if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```